# gson failed to deserialize date time after changing from 24 hour format in Android Phone Settings

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, sharedpreferences

so I have `User` class like this

```
class User() : Parcelable {

    var uid : String = ""
    var fullname : String = ""
    var email : String = ""
    var domicile : String = "Jakarta"
    var profilePicturePath : String = ""
    var createdAt : Date = Calendar.getInstance().time
    var verified : Boolean = false
    var banned : Boolean = false

}
```

as you can see, `createdAt` is in Date data type. after fetching user data from the server, then I save that User data in shared preference using `gson` like this

```
val gson = Gson()
val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

val json = gson.toJson(user)

with(sharedPref.edit()) {
     putString(USER_DATA, json)
     apply()
}
```

at this point, user still using 24 hour format data like the image below in their Android phone settings when saving user data in shared preference using gson

[image]

but if the user turn off that 24 hour format to use 1:00 PM format, then it will crash my app. it happened in this code when loading that saved user data from shared preference

```
val gson = Gson()
val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

val json = sharedPref.getString(USER_DATA, "")

if (json == null) {
   return null
} else {
   return gson.fromJson(json, User::class.java)  // <----- In This Line !!!
}
```

it seems failed to deserialize `createdAt` to date  from shared preference if the user change their date format. here is the error

> ```
> Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Jan 25, 2020 11:32:38
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:87)
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:75)
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:46)
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
> ```

I should clear the app cache/ data to stop my app from crashing, maybe because it is resaved using 1:00 PM format

what should I do to solve this crash ?
Java or Kotlin are okay

Comment: Maybe this will help?
https://github.com/google/gson/issues/935